# Enable Macro in Protected Worksheet

Tags: excel, password-protection, vba

I wrote a code for the worksheet, and everytime I change a number, if the varaince is greater than by 10%, 20%, or +20% it changes color. So i've used macro code on both "General" and "Private Sub Selection_Worksheet" so that everytime the cell's number changes, it would change the color.

I've locked and hidden some of the cells that show formulas,and wrote a code

```
    Sheets("Financials").Protect Password:="Ottawa", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

on both General and "Private Sub Selection_Worksheet" and it gives me a runtime error everytime i click on any cell.

How do I solve this issue? I only want them to use certain cells and still run the macro while being protected and hidden.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: You'll need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protection with `UserInterface:=True`is unfortunately somewhat misleading: If you reopen the file after saving, that status gets lost and the worksheet is again fully protected.

Therefore, it's better to change your code to handle the protection, too:

```
Private Const cStrPwd as String = "Ottawa"

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Your conditions to check if code should run go here, e.g.:
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:B10")) Is Nothing Or _
        Me.Range("B2") < 0.2 Then Exit Sub

    Me.Unprotect Password:=cStrPwd

    'Your code here
    MsgBox "You've successfully done something! Nice job, mate!"

    Me.Protect Password:=cStrPwd
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your response; however, i don't quite understand the function above since I'm new to VBA. 

If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:B10")) Is Nothing Or _ Me.Range("B2") < 0.2 Then Exit Sub 

what does that mean?

Comment: The line was just an example - in this example, it checks whether the selected range is outside the range of A1:B10 or if the value of cell B2 is less than 20%. If either condition is true, the remainder of the procedure is ignored. Hope that this makes things a bit clearer and you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: On a side note: depending on your need, I think 'Worksheet_Change` might be more suitable than `Worksheet_SelectionChange`: the latter is triggered every time you select any cell - the former is only triggered when you actually change something in the worksheet.